# Table search Javascript and jQuery CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, html-table

I want to search as by either Players Name, Nationality, or etc due to the long list of players. What is the Javascript and jQuery to use and is there any CSS needed to be input? I have tried various articles but it won't work.

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search Player"></input>

<table class="playersindex">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="wrapper-top" colspan="7">PLAYERS INDEX / 2013-14 / <span style="color: #ff3333;">SSSC</span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="23">NO.</th>
            <th class="player">PLAYER</th>
            <th></th>
            <th width="105">POSITION</th>
            <th width="30">AGE</th>
            <th width="105">NATIONALITY</th>
            <th width="105">FIRST SEASON</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="number">1</td>
            <td class="player"><a href="http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/players/profile.html/chuba-akpom">Kevin Siew</a></td>
            <td class="playerphoto"></td>
            <td>Goalkeeper</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>Singaporean</td>
            <td>2010/11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="number">2</td>
            <td class="player"><a href="http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/players/profile.html/chuba-akpom">Mohamad Hairul</a> (C)</td>
            <td class="playerphoto"></td>
            <td>Goalkeeper</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>Singaporean</td>
            <td>2010/11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="number">3</td>
            <td class="player"><a href="http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/players/profile.html/chuba-akpom">Nazir Samaluddin</a></td>
            <td class="playerphoto"></td>
            <td>Goalkeeper</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>Singaporean</td>
            <td>2010/11</td>
            ....
        <tr>
            <th width="23">NO.</th>
            <th class="player">PLAYER</th>
            <th></th>
            <th width="105">POSITION</th>
            <th width="30">AGE</th>
            <th width="105">NATIONALITY</th>
            <th width="105">FIRST SEASON</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th class="wrapper-bottom" colspan="7">LAST UPDATED:  10 December 2013, 1720</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<script type="text/Javascript">
    $("#search").keyup(function() {
        var value = this.value;

        $("table.playersindex").find("tr").each(function(index) {
            if (!index) return;
            var id = $(this).find("td").first().text();
            $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(value) !== -1);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#search").keyup(function () {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

    $("table tr").each(function (index) {
        if (!index) return;
        $(this).find("td").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
            var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
            $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
            return not_found;
        });
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AYLrh/)

Comment: Updated it but it doesn't seem to work (although it does in your demo). http://sefcl.sg/players/singapore-spurs-sc

Comment: k i will check and comment you

Comment: which file you put this script?

Comment: Can't I just include in the HTML body? There's one thing I clearly don't understand which is where do I include the js files to.

Comment: oh.. kindly include this code in above </head> `<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$("#search").keyup(function () {
var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();
$("table tr").each(function (index) {
if (!index) return;
$(this).find("td").each(function () {
var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
$(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
return not_found;
});
});
});
});
</script>`

Comment: Still, it doesn't seem to work.

`<head><script type="text/javascript"> $(window).load(function(){ $("#search").keyup(function () { var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim(); $("table tr").each(function (index) { if (!index) return; $(this).find("td").each(function () { var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim(); var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1); $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found); return not_found; }); }); }); }); </script></head>

<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search Player"></input>

<table class="playersindex">`

Comment: hello dont put this on your code `<p><head> </head</p>` you just place this code only anywhere dont add anything before and after `<script type="text/javascript"> $(window).load(function(){ $("#search").keyup(function () { var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim(); $("table tr").each(function (index) { if (!index) return; $(this).find("td").each(function () { var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim(); var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1); $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found); return not_found; }); }); }); }); </script>`

Comment: Yep, thats what I did initially. But it didn't work. I included it at the very beginning. `<script type="text/javascript"> $(window).load(function(){ $("#search").keyup(function () { var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim(); $("table tr").each(function (index) { if (!index) return; $(this).find("td").each(function () { var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim(); var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1); $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found); return not_found; }); }); }); }); </script>

<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search Player"></input>

<table class="playersindex">`

Comment: ok open your js file named script.js and then add code TABS heading below `$("#search").keyup(function () {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

    $("table.playersindex tr").each(function (index) {
        if (!index) return;
        $(this).find("td").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
            var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
            $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
            return not_found;
        });
    });
});`